# Why does cleaning istringstream fail?

Tags: c++, string, c++11, istringstream, sstream

While converting a string to integer I just fail to clear my istringstream to place in another number. I have tried all kinds of different solutions but it just wont work. There are a few work arounds but I'd like to learn to know why...

So basically this is how my code looks like

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

int main() {

  std::string a = "153";
  std::string c = "2556";

  int b;

  std::istringstream convert(a);

  convert >> b;

  std::cout << b << std::endl;

  convert.str( std::string() );
  //convert.str("");
  convert.clear();

  convert(c);

  convert >> b;

  std::cout << b << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

And the following output error

```
C:\...\string to int.cpp|28|error: no match for call to '(std::istringstream {aka std::basic_istringstream<char>}) (std::string&)'|
```

Thanks :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't call the constructor `convert(c)` of an object once already constructed. To set a new string to parse you need to call the function `str(c)`. So you need to change it to:

```
convert.str(c);
```

Answer (score 2):

`convert(c);` would require `std::istringstream` to define a function call operator `operator()` that can be called with an lvalue of type `std::string`. This is not the case.

You can use `clear()` and `str()`:

```
std::string a = "153";
std::string c = "2556";
int b{ 0 };
std::istringstream convert{ a };
convert >> b;
std::cout << b << std::endl;
convert.clear();
convert.str(c);
convert >> b;
std::cout << b << std::endl;
```